# Multiply vectorized 2D square matrix and compressed tridiagonal matrix in CUDA

Tags: c++, matrix, cuda, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have two matrices

```
#define MATRIX_SIZE 20
#define BLOCK_SIZE 2
#define TILE_SIZE  2

double** A
double** B
```

Matrix A is dense, Matrix B is tridiagonal. I have created a vectorized representation of A

```
/* sz = A.rowlen = B.rowlen = A.collen = B.collen */
double* A1d = matrix_to_vector(sz, A);
```

I have also created a compressed representation of B with the following function

```
double* l_array = new double(sz - 1);
double* m_array = new double(sz);
double* r_array = new double(sz-1);
int current_l_idx = 0;
int current_m_idx = 0;
int current_r_idx = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < sz; j++) {
    if ((i == j+1) || (i-1 == j)) {
      l_array[current_l_idx] = B[i][j];
      current_l_idx++;
    }
    else if ((i == j-1) || (i+1 == j)) {
      r_array[current_r_idx] = B[i][j];
      current_r_idx++;
    }
    else if (i == j) {
      m_array[current_m_idx] = B[i][j];
      current_m_idx++;
    }
  }
}
```

I then create an empty 2D vectorized matrix E as well as all my objects for `CUDA`

```
double* E1d = matrix_to_vector(sz, E);

double* d_A
double* d_B_l;
double* d_B_m;
double* d_B_r;
double* d_E;

size_t sizeA = sz * sz * sizeof(double);
size_t sizeB_lr = (sz - 1) * sizeof(double);
size_t sizeB_m = sz * sizeof(double);

cudaMalloc(&d_A, sizeA);
cudaMalloc(&d_B_l. sizeB_lr);
cudaMalloc(&d_B_m, sizeB_m);
cudaMalloc(&d_B_r, sizeB_lr);
cudaMalloc(&d_E, sizeA);

cudaMemcpy(d_A, A1d, sizeA, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(d_B_l, l_array, sizeB_lr, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(d_B_m, m_array, sizeB_m, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(d_B_r, r_array, sizeB_lr, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(d_E, E1d, sizeA, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

dim3 threads(BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE);
dim3 grid(MATRIX_SIZE / threads.x, MATRIX_SIZE / threads.y);

cudakernel<<<grid, threads>>>(sz, d_A, d_B_l, d_B_m, d_B_r, d_E);
```

I can perform this multiplication serially but I, unfortunately, have NO idea how to implement this on the CUDA device

Assumptions

1. A and B are always square
2. sz will always be evenly divisible by BLOCK_SIZE and TILE_SIZE
3. BLOCK_SIZE will always equal TILE_SIZE

Comment: If you're willing to convert your tridiagonal matrix to CSR storage, you could just use CUSPARSE [csrmm](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#cusparse-lt-t-gt-csrmm)  Since your matrices are square, the operation you want (dense x sparse) can be achieved with transpose operations and reversing the order of the csrmm (sparse x dense).

Comment: @Robert CSR is acceptable, but unfortunately I can not use libraries. :(

Comment: matrix multiplication computes the sum of a row (of A) times a column (of B) for each point in the output matrix (C).  Since B is your tridiagonal matrix, it means you'll have just 3 elements in the column of B for each output element (or 2 for the edge cases).  A simple approach could be to properly restrict the for-loop (to just do 3 multiplications) and come up with appropriate indices to index into your B vectors.

Comment: @Robert I agree. That was the approach suggested to me. I am just not very good at matrix iteration on the device.  :( Can you provide how you would code this kernel using that approach?

Comment: Is this for homework?  If you understand how to do a dense matrix-matrix multiply, you should be able to figure out which 3 products terms are needed for each element in the tridiagonal case.  Figuring this out (the 3 product terms of A and B, that will be needed for each result in C) really has nothing to do with the GPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect based on your setup code that you are looking for a tiled shared-memory approach to this kind of matrix multiplication, and I'm not really wanting to do your homework for you, so I'll demonstrate an example that *doesn't* use shared memory.

If you understand how matrix multiplication works, and you also understand how to create an ordinary [shared memory GPU matrix multiply kernel](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#shared-memory__matrix-multiplication-shared-memory), converting the following code to use shared memory should be relatively straightforward:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DSIZE 256
#define BSIZE 32
#define TOL 0.0001
typedef  double mytype;

#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)




// C = A x B
// A,B,C are all dense
template <typename T>
__global__ void mm(const T * __restrict__ A, const T * __restrict__ B, T * __restrict__ C, const int sz){

  int idx = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
  int idy = threadIdx.y+blockDim.y*blockIdx.y;

  if ((idx < sz) && (idy < sz)){
    T temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
      temp += A[idy*sz+i]*B[i*sz+idx];
    C[idy*sz+idx] = temp;}
}


// C = A x B
// A,C are dense, B is tridiagonal
template <typename T>
__global__ void mmt(const T * __restrict__ A, const T * __restrict__ B_l, const T * __restrict__ B_m, const T * __restrict__ B_r, T * __restrict__ C, const int sz){

  int idx = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
  int idy = threadIdx.y+blockDim.y*blockIdx.y;

  if ((idx < sz) && (idy < sz)){
    T temp = 0;
    if (idx > 0)      temp += A[idy*sz+(idx-1)]*B_r[idx-1];
                      temp += A[idy*sz+(idx)  ]*B_m[idx];
    if (idx < (sz-1)) temp += A[idy*sz+(idx+1)]*B_l[idx];
    C[idy*sz+idx] = temp;}
}



int main(){

  mytype *d_A, *h_A, *d_B, *h_B, *d_C, *h_Cd, *h_Cs, *d_B_l, *h_B_l, *d_B_m, *h_B_m, *d_B_r, *h_B_r;
  size_t msz  = DSIZE*DSIZE;
  size_t mszb = msz*sizeof(mytype);
// host side allocations
  h_A = (mytype *)malloc(mszb);
  h_B = (mytype *)malloc(mszb);
  h_Cd =(mytype *)malloc(mszb);
  h_Cs =(mytype *)malloc(mszb);
  h_B_l = (mytype *)malloc((DSIZE-1)*sizeof(mytype));
  h_B_r = (mytype *)malloc((DSIZE-1)*sizeof(mytype));
  h_B_m = (mytype *)malloc(    DSIZE*sizeof(mytype));
  if (!h_A || !h_B || !h_Cd || !h_Cs || !h_B_l || !h_B_r || !h_B_m) {printf("malloc fail\n"); return -1;}
// device side allocations
  cudaMalloc(&d_A, mszb);
  cudaMalloc(&d_B, mszb);
  cudaMalloc(&d_C, mszb);
  cudaMalloc(&d_B_l, (DSIZE-1)*sizeof(mytype));
  cudaMalloc(&d_B_r, (DSIZE-1)*sizeof(mytype));
  cudaMalloc(&d_B_m,     DSIZE*sizeof(mytype));
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMalloc fail");
// prepare A, B matrices

/*
       |1 1 1 ...|
   A = |2 2 2 ...|
       |3 3 3 ...|
       |4 4 4 ...|
       |...      |


       |2 1 0 ...|   B_l = left/lower subdiagonal    (i.e. all 3's)
   B = |3 2 1 ...|   B_m = middle/main diagonal      (i.e. all 2's)
       |0 3 2 ...|   B_r = right/upper superdiagonal (i.e. all 1's)
       |0 0 3 ...|
       |...      |
*/



  for (int i = 0; i < DSIZE; i++){
    if (i < DSIZE-1){
      h_B_r[i] = 1;
      h_B_l[i] = 3;}
    h_B_m[i] = 2;
    for (int j = 0; j < DSIZE; j++){
      h_A[i*DSIZE+j] = i+1;
      if (j==i+1)      h_B[i*DSIZE+j] = 1;
      else if (j==i)   h_B[i*DSIZE+j] = 2;
      else if (j==i-1) h_B[i*DSIZE+j] = 3;
      else             h_B[i*DSIZE+j] = 0;}}

// copy data to device

  cudaMemcpy(d_A, h_A, mszb, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(d_B, h_B, mszb, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(d_B_l, h_B_l, (DSIZE-1)*sizeof(mytype), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(d_B_r, h_B_r, (DSIZE-1)*sizeof(mytype), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(d_B_m, h_B_m,     DSIZE*sizeof(mytype), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy1 fail");

// perform dense-dense multiply

  dim3 block(BSIZE,BSIZE);
  dim3  grid((DSIZE+block.x-1)/block.x, (DSIZE+block.y-1)/block.y);

  cudaMemset(d_C, 0, mszb);
  mm<<<grid, block>>>(d_A, d_B, d_C, DSIZE);
  cudaMemcpy(h_Cd, d_C, mszb, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy 2/kernel fail");

// perform dense-sparse multiply

  cudaMemset(d_C, 0, mszb);
  mmt<<<grid, block>>>(d_A, d_B_l, d_B_m, d_B_r, d_C, DSIZE);
  cudaMemcpy(h_Cs, d_C, mszb, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy 3/kernel fail");

// compare results

  for (int i = 0; i < DSIZE; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < DSIZE; j++)
      if (abs(h_Cs[i*DSIZE+j] - h_Cd[i*DSIZE+j]) > TOL) {printf("results mismatch at (%d, %d) dense: %f sparse: %f\n", i, j, h_Cd[i*DSIZE+j], h_Cs[i*DSIZE+j]); return -1;}
  printf("Success!\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Notes:

1. All of the global memory accesses in the `mmt` kernel (i.e. for `A`, the `B` vectors, and `C`) should properly coalesce across threads. Therefore, a conversion to use shared memory should also easily yield non-bank-conflicted access to shared memory.
2. While studying this code may be useful for learning, I recommend any serious sparse-dense matrix multiplication be done with routines from CUSPARSE such as [csrmm](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#cusparse-lt-t-gt-csrmm).  It will almost certainly be much more efficient (faster) than the above code, and likely faster than any shared memory conversion of the above code as well.